# Demora al generar un PDF con Python y Reportlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

mi duda esta en el tiempo que se demora mi aplicación en el momento en que deseo generar un reporte PDF, con python y reportlab. mientras sean hasta 20 paginas la aplicación no se demora mucho, en solo segundos genera el reporte en PDF, pero cuando el reporte que se va a generar tiene aproximadamente 70 paginas o más, el tiempo supera los 3 minutos, el problema es que la aplicación genera reportes hasta de 1000 páginas o más, como puedo solucionar esto, o que otra alternativa tengo para generar este tipo de reportes en PDF.

Adjunto el código del reporte...

```
__author__ = "FelipeMedel"
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas    
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, portrait    
from reportlab.lib.units import cm, mm    
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics    
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont    
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, BaseDocTemplate, Frame, PageTemplate, Image, TableStyle    
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle    
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER, TA_LEFT    
import os    
from .... import session    
import uuid    
from ....models import DefaultValue    
from ....utils.math_ext import _round    
from ....utils.image_converter import ImagesConverter    
from ...libs.functions import paragraph_over_flow, paragraph_over_flow_height    
import time    

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'Arial.ttf'))    
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial-Bold', 'Arial_Bold.ttf'))    
pdfmetrics.registerFontFamily(
    'Arial',
    normal='Arial',
    bold='Arial-Bold'
)

class NumberedCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._saved_page_states = []

    def showPage(self):
        self._saved_page_states.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def save(self):
        num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
        for state in self._saved_page_states:
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.draw_page_footer_n_header(num_pages)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    def draw_page_footer_n_header(self, page_count):
        preview_data = AccountingYearClosePreview.preview_data

        # TABLAS HEADER -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        style_table_company = TableStyle(
            [
                # ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                # ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2.5 * cm),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2.5 * cm),
                ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.05 * cm),
                ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP')
            ]
        )

        # TABLAS HEADER - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # ESTILOS HEADER ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        texto_company = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        texto_company.fontName = 'Arial'
        texto_company.fontSize = 12
        texto_company.leading = 12
        texto_company.alignment = TA_CENTER

        texto_company_nit = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        texto_company_nit.fontName = 'Arial'
        texto_company_nit.fontSize = 10
        texto_company_nit.leading = 10
        texto_company_nit.alignment = TA_CENTER

        texto_derecha = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        texto_derecha.fontName = 'Arial'
        texto_derecha.fontSize = 8
        texto_derecha.leading = 8
        texto_derecha.alignment = TA_RIGHT

        texto_izquierda = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        texto_izquierda.fontName = 'Arial'
        texto_izquierda.fontSize = 8
        texto_izquierda.leading = 8
        texto_izquierda.alignment = TA_LEFT

        texto_centro = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        texto_centro.fontName = 'Arial'
        texto_centro.fontSize = 8
        texto_centro.leading = 8
        texto_centro.alignment = TA_CENTER

        texto_justificado = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        texto_justificado.fontName = 'Arial'
        texto_justificado.fontSize = 8
        texto_justificado.leading = 8
        texto_justificado.alignment = TA_JUSTIFY

        # ESTILOS HEADER - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        def header(cnv):
            cnv.saveState()

            # TABLA DATOS COMPAÑIA --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            company_name = '{0} - {1}'.format(preview_data['company_name'], preview_data['branch_name'])
            nit = preview_data['nit'].split('-')

            x = 0 if preview_data['libro_1'] == '0' else 1
            y = 0 if preview_data['libro_2'] == '0' else 1

            datos_company = [
                [
                    Paragraph('<b>{0}</b>'.format(
                        paragraph_over_flow_height(text='' if x == 0 and y == 0 else company_name.upper(),
                                                   width=12.8,
                                                   no_par=3,
                                                   font_size=12,
                                                   leading=12,
                                                   left_indent=2.8,
                                                   right_indent=2.8)), texto_company)
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph('' if x == 0 and y == 0 else '<b>{0}-{1}</b>'.format('.'.join([str(nit[0])[i:i + 3]
                                           for i in range(0, len(str(nit[0])), 3)]), nit[1]), texto_company_nit)
                ]
            ]

            tabla_company = Table(
                datos_company,
                [19.6 * cm],
                style=style_table_company
            )

            tabla_company.wrap(19.6 * cm, 4 * cm)
            tabla_company.drawOn(cnv, 1 * cm, 25.5 * cm)

            # TABLA DATOS COMPAÑIA - FIN --------------------------------------------------------------------------

            # LOGO ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            image = None if preview_data['image'] is None \
                else "{0},{1}".format("data:image/*;base64",
                                      ImagesConverter.img_convert_to_base64(preview_data['image'].image))

            if image is not None:
                img = Image(image, width=2.3 * cm, height=2.3 * cm)
                img.wrap(2.3 * cm, 2.3 * cm)
                img.drawOn(cnv, 1 * cm, 24.5 * cm)

            # LOGO - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            # FECHA Y PAGINADO ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            page_number = Paragraph('Página {0} de {1}'.format(self._pageNumber, page_count), texto_derecha)
            page_number.wrap(3 * cm, 0.5 * cm)
            page_number.drawOn(cnv, 17.6 * cm, 25.1 * cm)

            # FECHA Y PAGINADO - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            cnv.restoreState()

        def footer(cnv):
            cnv.saveState()

            # FACTURA Y FECHA -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            fecha_hora = Paragraph(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), texto_derecha)
            fecha_hora.wrap(4 * cm, 1 * cm)
            fecha_hora.drawOn(cnv, 16.6 * cm, 1 * cm)

            # FACTURA Y FECHA - FIN -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            # VALIDACION PARA DOCUMENTO ANULADO -------------------------------------------------------------------

            if preview_data['annuled']:
                msm = 'ANULADO'
                anulado(cnv, msm)

            # VALIDACION PARA DOCUMENTO ANULADO - FIN -------------------------------------------------------------

            cnv.restoreState()

        def anulado(cvn, cadena):
            cvn.saveState()

            cvn.translate(18.2 * cm, 21 * cm)
            cvn.setFontSize(100, 30)
            cvn.setFillColorRGB(1, 0, 0, alpha=0.3)
            cvn.rotate(35)
            cvn.drawRightString(0, 0, cadena)

            cvn.restoreState()

        header(self)
        footer(self)


class AccountingYearClosePreview:

    preview_data = None

    @staticmethod
    def make_preview_pdf(preview_data):
        AccountingYearClosePreview.preview_data = preview_data

        outfilename = "{0}.pdf".format(uuid.uuid1())
        outfiledir = os.getcwd().replace('aplicacion/registros', 'Assets/documents')
        outfilepath = os.path.join(outfiledir, outfilename)

        # ESTILOS TABLA DETALLES ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        style_table_descripcion = TableStyle(
            [
                # ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                # ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (5, -1), 0),
                ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('LINEABOVE', (0, 1), (5, 1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('LINEABOVE', (0, 0), (5, 0), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
                ('SPAN', (0, 1), (5, 1)),
                ('SPAN', (0, 2), (5, 2)),
            ]
        )

        estilo = TableStyle(
            [
                # ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                # ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('LEFTPADDING', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 0.1 * cm),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (0, -1), 0.1 * cm),
                ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP')
            ]
        )

        estilo_total = TableStyle(
            [
                # ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                # ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('LINEABOVE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('LINEABOVE', (0, 2), (-1, 2), 1, (0, 0, 0))
            ]
        )

        estilo_cabecera = TableStyle(
            [
                ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
            ]
        )

        text_right = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        text_right.fontName = 'Arial'
        text_right.fontSize = 8
        text_right.leading = 8
        text_right.alignment = TA_RIGHT

        text_left = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        text_left.fontName = 'Arial'
        text_left.fontSize = 8
        text_left.leading = 8
        text_left.alignment = TA_LEFT

        text_center = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        text_center.fontName = 'Arial'
        text_center.fontSize = 8
        text_center.leading = 8
        text_center.alignment = TA_CENTER

        text_center_contabilidad = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
        text_center_contabilidad.fontName = 'Arial'
        text_center_contabilidad.fontSize = 12
        text_center_contabilidad.leading = 12
        text_center_contabilidad.alignment = TA_CENTER

        # ESTILOS TABLA DETALLES - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # VARIABLES LIBROS  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        x = 0 if preview_data['libro_1'] == '0' else 1
        y = 0 if preview_data['libro_2'] == '0' else 1

        # VARIABLES LIBROS - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # TABLA DESCRIPCION -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (x == 1 and y == 0) or (y == 1 and x == 0):

            if x == 0 and y == 1:
                contabilizacion = 'LIBRO 2'
            else:
                contabilizacion = 'LIBRO 1'

            datos_cabeza = [
                [
                    Paragraph('', text_center),
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph('<b>{0}</b>'.format(contabilizacion), text_center_contabilidad),
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph('', text_center)
                ]
            ]

            datos_descripcion = [
                [
                    Paragraph('<b>NÚMERO</b>', text_left),
                    Paragraph('<b>DOCUMENTO</b>', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>FECHA</b>', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>CANTIDAD</b>', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>VALOR</b>', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>TOTAL</b>', text_right)
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph('<b>{0}</b>'.format('texto de prueba'.upper()), text_left),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right)
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph('<b>OTRO TEXTO</b>'.upper(), text_left),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right)
                ]
            ]

        # TABLA DESCRIPCION - FIN -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # DETALLES ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        datos = []

        if (x == 1 and y == 0) or (x == 0 and y == 1):

            for i in range(20):

                datos.append(
                    [
                        Paragraph('0000 00 000', text_left),
                        Paragraph('ASD 0123456789', text_right),
                        Paragraph(time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), text_right),
                        Paragraph('{:20,.{}f}'.format(_round(1, default_decimals.quantityDecimals),
                                                      default_decimals.quantityDecimals), text_right),
                        Paragraph('{:20,.{}f}'.format(_round(1234567890, default_decimals.valueDecimals),
                                                      default_decimals.valueDecimals), text_right),
                        Paragraph('{:20,.{}f}'.format(_round(1234567890, default_decimals.valueDecimals),
                                                      default_decimals.valueDecimals), text_right)
                    ]
                )
        else:
            vacio = []
            vacio.append(
                [
                    Paragraph('', text_left),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right)
                ]
            )

        # DETALLES - FIN ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # TOTAL ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # datos_total = []

        if (x == 1 and y == 0) or (x == 0 and y == 1):

            datos_total = [
                [
                    Paragraph('', text_left),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>TOTAL</b>', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>{:20,.{}f}</b>'.format(_round(0, default_decimals.valueDecimals),
                                                  default_decimals.valueDecimals), text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>{:20,.{}f}</b>'.format(_round(0, default_decimals.valueDecimals),
                                                  default_decimals.valueDecimals), text_right),
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph('', text_left),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('', text_right),
                    Paragraph('<b>{:20,.{}f}</b>'.format(_round(0, default_decimals.valueDecimals),
                                                  default_decimals.valueDecimals), text_right),
                ]
            ]

        # TOTAL - FIN ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        doc = BaseDocTemplate(outfilepath, pagesize=portrait(letter))

        doc.addPageTemplates(
            [
                PageTemplate(
                    frames=[
                        Frame(
                            x1=1 * cm,
                            y1=1.6 * cm,
                            width=19.6 * cm,
                            height=23.3 * cm,
                            leftPadding=0,
                            rightPadding=0,
                            bottomPadding=0,
                            topPadding=0,
                            id=None,
                            showBoundary=False
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )

        if (x == 1 and y == 0) or (x == 0 and y == 1):

            doc.build(
                [Table(
                    datos_cabeza,
                    [19.6 * cm],
                    [0.1 * cm, 0.8 * cm, 0.4 * cm],
                    style=estilo_cabecera
                ), Table(
                    datos_descripcion,
                    [6.6 * cm, 2.5 * cm, 1.6 * cm, 1.7 * cm, 3.6 * cm, 3.6 * cm],
                    0.5 * cm,
                    style=style_table_descripcion
                ), Table(
                    datos,
                    [6.6 * cm, 2.5 * cm, 1.6 * cm, 1.7 * cm, 3.6 * cm, 3.6 * cm],
                    style=estilo
                ), Table(
                    datos_total,
                    [6.6 * cm, 2.5 * cm, 1.6 * cm, 1.7 * cm, 3.6 * cm, 3.6 * cm],
                    style=estilo_total
                )], canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas
            )
        else:
            doc.build(
                [Table(
                    vacio,
                    [6.6 * cm, 2.5 * cm, 1.6 * cm, 1.7 * cm, 3.6 * cm, 3.6 * cm],
                    style=style_table_descripcion
                )], canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas
            )

        return "{0}".format(outfi
```

lename)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bueno, desde hace un tiempo me encontraba buscando y buscando por todos lados una posible solución, para la demora en el proceso de generar un reporte, así que probando y probando varias librerías, encontré una llamada **FPDF**, [información aquí](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf), de igual forma si desean tener una idea mas clara de las opciones que se pueden utilizar para realizar los reportes, en este link encontraran el  [Manual de Referencia](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), entre todas las opciones que probe, esta fue la mejor, el sistema que estoy terminando de desarrollar es contable, así que para movimientos contables me sirvió mucho, **1000 Páginas en 7.39 segundos**, la desventaja que tiene, es que toca hacer el reporte a código, pero el resultado es satisfactorio...

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya sabes, `Python` es un lenguaje interpretado, y ya ves de donde sale toda la magia de `python` y sus funciones, mientras que en otros lenguajes una implementación tomaría muchas lineas ,en Python es realmente sencillo pero el tiempo de ejecución es mucho mayor al de un lenguaje compilado.  Pero en fin toma estas consideraciones.

1. Puedes encapsular la función con [cython](http://cython.org/)
2. Considera hacer tareas en background con [celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery)

Actualmente yo uso [celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery) , ya que sucede lo mismo tarda demasiado, así que envió la tarea para su ejecución y cuando termina envío un correo al usuario avisando que ya esta su reporte listo para descargar.

Comment: me parece una solución considerable, pero el problema es que el reporte se usa en un visualizador que esta embebido en la aplicación ("Modal") para ser exacto. por el momento su demora es poca cuando son paginas hasta 50 con tiempo considerable, cuando se trata de mas paginas es mas lento el proceso, pero en este caso se me complica, porque si cierro el modal, el servicio que tengo para generar el reporte y mostrarlo, no se completaría... no se si estoy siendo claro con lo que digo... igual gracias, me documentare sobre **Celery**

Comment: Si te entiendo, yo hacia lo mismo.  me toco hacer API's especificas, y reconstruir muchas funciones, pero es algo que pasa, incluso, el mismo servidor no soporta y retorna 504, es mejor hacerlo con background,  lo único que hago es que consumo una Api , que llama una tarea, y la tarea ejecuta lo que antes se ejecutaba directamente en el front, y cuando termina lo sube a dropbox y envía un email.